# Check for new entries in a DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am trying to build an application that will query a db, and send data somewhere as it comes into the database.

I can get the data I want from the database using this code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `signals` order by `time` DESC LIMIT 100";
$result = mysqli_query($DatabasePointer,$sql) 
    or die(mysqli_error($DatabasePointer));
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row_cnt>0)
{
    $array = array();
    $i=0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $i++;
        //$a = array();
        $epoch = $row['time'];
        // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
        $dt = new DateTime("@$epoch");

        if(
            ($row['symbol'] === 'USDJPYecn') 
            || ($row['symbol'] === 'USDCADecn') 
            || ($row['symbol'] === 'EURUSDecn')
            ) 
        {
            if(
                ($row['timeframe'] === 'M5') 
                || ($row['timeframe'] === 'M15')
                )  
            {
                $a = array(
                    "time" => $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    "signal" => $row['signal'],
                    "symbol" => $row['symbol'],
                    "price" => $row['price'],
                    "timeframe" => $row['timeframe'],
                    "epoch" => $row['time'],
                    "candel" => $row['candel'] 
                    );
                $array[] = $a;
             }
        }

    } // while

    echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);           
}
```

However, I am not sure how to revise the code to check to see if the data is new, or has already been sent out to another source. I am also unsure how to revise the code to only send new data as it hits the db, not an entire array of data like I am calling now.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `tdisignals` order by `time` DESC LIMIT 100";
$result = mysqli_query($DatabasePointer,$sql) 
    or die(mysqli_error($DatabasePointer));
$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row_cnt>0)
{
    $array = array();
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $i++;
        //$a = array();
        $epoch = $row['time']; 
        // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
        $dt = new DateTime("@$epoch");

        if( 
            $row['symbol'] === 'USDJPYecn' 
            || ($row['symbol'] === 'USDCADecn') 
            || ($row['symbol'] === 'GBPUSDecn'))
        {
            if(
                $row['timeframe'] === 'M5')
                || ($row['timeframe'] === 'M15'))
            {

                $a = array(
                    "time" => $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    "signal" => $row['signal'],
                    "symbol" => $row['symbol'],
                    "price" => $row['price'],
                    "timeframe" => $row['timeframe'],
                    "epoch" => $row['time'],
                    "candel" => $row['candel'],
                    );

                $array[] = $a;
            }

        }

    }

    // echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    $fuegostore = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    // $sql2 = "INSERT INTO fuegosync (time, lastsync) ".
    //          "VALUES ('$date', '$fuegostore')";
    // $result2 = mysqli_query($DatabasePointer,$sql2) 
       // or die(mysqli_error($DatabasePointer));
    $sql3="SELECT lastsync, MAX(CAST(time AS CHAR)) FROM `fuegosync`";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($DatabasePointer,$sql3) 
        or die(mysqli_error($DatabasePointer));

    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($result3);

    if($row2[0] === $fuegostore)
        echo 'No New Signals';
    else
        echo 'New Signals';
                    ///OPTION 1:
                    //print_r (json_encode($array[0], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
                    //OPTION 2:
                    foreach($array as $x) {
                        if(strtotime($array[0]['time']) >= $row2[1]) {
                        echo '<br /><span>'.$x['signal'].' - '.$x['symbol'].' - '.$x['price'].'<br />';
                        } else {
                            echo 'No New Signals';
                        }
                }

    echo $row2[0];
}
```

This code is successfully detecting a new data hitting the database. What I am struggling with now, is revising the code to only display the newly detected data piece, not the entire array as you see it.

NEW EDIT:
I have gotten the code to display only the newest piece of data, but now I have a conundrum.
If I poll the database say every minute, and a new piece of data hits the db, the script will pick it up -- however if another new piece of data hits the db seconds after the first new piece was sent to target, the second new piece will totally get ignored because the poll would be every minute. I would basically have to poll the database every few seconds... and that sounds like a performance nightmare...

The grayed out OPTION 1  is what displays the newest data, but would skip a newer piece before a minute based poll unless the db was polled every second.
OPTION 2 works, but displays the entire array... so I am unsure how to revise the code to only display the newest pieces, not the entire thing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make a `sent` column or some boolean column and update it when you send. Then you'll know which records have been sent.

Comment: or send a timestamp (of the last visit) to the script and filter via sql by that.

Comment: I had the same idea as @chris85 but it might cause problems elsewhere to add a new value at this point so you could also have a new table called `signals_sent` and store the id of the signals that have been sent in there.

Comment: Okay so I made a "lastcheck" colum. I can put the date/time in there every time the script checks the DB. My assumption is that I would then have the query check the date/time in lastcheck, and only pull signals since that date/time? Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: For the best approach you would query the target location you may have previously sent the information to and get the MAX datetime it was changed or Increment and then query your SOURCE table for datetime's or increments greater than.  If you cannot query the target then you can store values in a table that stores last datetime synched and or actually a related table to store the status of what has been synched.

Comment: So you have data, it comes into your database. Somewhere later via something like a cron job you are checking for new data and trying to send it somewhere? So the data is either sent or not sent? Can it be sent multiple times? Please can you be a bit clearer with the question, finding it hand to understand but would try to help.

Comment: there are different points you need to know : can you add row-level data in both source and target ? what the criticality of your data in target (could you lose a row ?) ? do you have a restricted bandwidth ? how huge is your dataset ?

Comment: The target is actually a web API which relays the information to application called "Telegram". The source is a mysql db, and yes I can add row level data. Bandwidth should not be restricted on either end. The dataset is moderate.

Comment: @user3259138 ok so the `One-sided and check-less` part of my answer seem the best choice then I think

Comment: Let me update with what I have right now... There has been a lot of progress made from all your suggestions.

Comment: Okay updated with the current code, and what I am struggling with

Comment: While I am reviewing, how does `@` fit in with `$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch");`?

Comment: For @ - http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/php

Comment: So an update, I have figured out how to view the latest data, but now I have a problem. If I don't poll the database every few seconds, say I do it only every 1 minute and a new piece of data gets entered seconds after the newest data was already sent to target, then that second newest piece will never get sent to target... I am totally unsure how to get around that. Any suggestions guys?

Comment: Added an update so you guys can understand and hopefully point me in the right direction

Comment: Does anybody know if there is a way to filter through a whole array, and unset any of the entries in an array that do not match a certain condition? For example, filter through an array, and check each entries "time" value to see whether or not it is greater than a specified time? I am trying to work with array keys, array search, and things like that. Array search might work, but only returns 1 result. I would need to get all the entries that meet the condition and remove them....

Comment: @user3259138 you are trying to go with the timestamp based solution ? can't you just add a `send` field in your DB ? it'll be way easier for you

Comment: @Blag do you mean like to each piece of data add a send field?

Comment: @user3259138 yes, on your source DB, you add a `send` field `DEFAULT 0` . if you can, it'll help you a lot in your task as explained in my answer

Comment: Yes I can. I actually added one, but was not sure how to incorporate it with the code above.

Comment: @user3259138 just add me the table schema with the `send` field in your post; i'll have some time to make you the code tomorrow pm (UTC)

Comment: Okay! Just let me know when you are free.

Comment: Looking forward to learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Secured

One of the most secure way to do this kind of thing is :

- having an incremented field on source
- allowing a query on target

**Step-by-step, source driven**

1. you add some data in source, with their auto-incremented `id`
2. you query your target from source and ask for the last `id` know
3. with this `id`, from source, you get all new record, and query with these data an insert page on target

**Alternate, target driven**

1. you add some data in source, with their auto-incremented `id`
2. your target get his bigger `id` and ask source for new data
3. target update himself

And you can go to step one again. If you are careful on your insert (use of roll-back, break full batch on one fail), you should have a perfect target whenever the fail on the source / target link, and the bandwidth is as low as it could.

---

## One-sided and check-less

This allow to send batch of data from source without answer nor action of target.

*This don’t care if the data is lost on the way, it only send once.*

- having a three states field `send` on source

**Step-by-step**

1. you add some data in source, with their `send` by default on `0`
2. you set every `send ==0` on `send = -1`
3. select every `-1` and send them to the target
4. update `-1` to `1`

Go back to step one.

This allow you big batch without having to put a `lock write` waiting the send script, and be sure you can't have some line that drop between the send one.

---

## Timestamp

This look a lot like the previous one, but instead of a field on every row, we just use a new table to keep the last sync :

**Step-by-step**

1. you add some data in source, with their timestamp
2. you get the current timestamp - 1 (one second before now)
3. you get the last sync timestamp (or 0 if it's your first sync)
4. select and send lines where `timestampOfPost <= timestamp-1` and `timestampOfPost > timestampLastSync`
5. update your last sync timestamp with the `timestamp - 1` of point 2.

Timestamp can be tricky if you don't use the "go 1seconde back in time" and keep it in a variable, as you can lose some update :

If you send at `***754`(.1)s, every line from `***754`(.2)s to (.9)s will be see as send as we have done the timestamp `***754` and will start the next send at `***755`.

Comment: I ended up using the check-less one. Used a timestamp on the table.

Comment: Also ended up using a separate table to keep track of the sync in combo with the timestamp on the actual pieces of data.